# Validate Password and confirm_password field:

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I don't know how to validate Password and Confirm_password field to make sure both are same. Anyone please help for this question.

This is controller:

```
public class test_validation {

public test_validation(ApexPages.StandardController con){}

    public Student_Sports_Registration__c testvalidation{get;set;}
    public test_validation() {
        testvalidation = new Student_Sports_Registration__c();
    }

    public PageReference Save(){

        insert testvalidation;
        return null;

}
}
```

This is my VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="test_validation">


  <apex:form id="commentForm">

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Enter Name:"> </apex:outputLabel>
<apex:inputField id="name" required="true" value="{!testvalidation.Name}" />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Enter Department:"> </apex:outputLabel>
<apex:inputField required="true" value="{!testvalidation.Department_list__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Enter Email:"> </apex:outputLabel>
<apex:inputField required="true" id="email" value="{!testvalidation.Email__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel  value="{!$Label.site.password}" for="password"></apex:outputLabel>
<apex:inputSecret required="true" id="pwd" value="{!testvalidation.Password__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Enter Confirm_Password:"></apex:outputLabel>
<apex:inputSecret id="cpwd" value="{!testvalidation.Confirm_Password__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</center>

       <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" id="save" value="Save"/>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thank you,

Comment: Have you been through the Trailhead visualforce module and the Apex Test class modules yet which you can find from this link: [Trailhead Modules](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules)? Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just using:

```
public PageReference Save(){
    if(testvalidation.Password__c == testvalidation.Confirm_Password__c){
         insert testvalidation;
         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM, 'Registered.'));
    }else{
         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'The passwords are not matching.'));
    }
    return null;
}
```

And :

```
<apex:page controller="test_validation">
  <apex:form id="commentForm">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Registration">
      <apex:pageMessages />
```